# How do I access a file that is bound to a form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a file bound to a form in this manner:
(forms.py)
    class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
        wbfile  = forms.FileField(label='Upload workbook' , help_text='Please Ensure file is in .xlsx format')

Now I have can access this in a view function using request.FILES['wbfile']. But I want to send this file to a template and then to another view function. So I bound it to a form like this:

```
f = form.fields['wbfile']
```

Now I want to save this file in the disk, but how do I access this file, this is what I am trying:

```
f = form.fields['file'].value()
with open(/tmp/xyz) as destination:
    contents = f.read()
    destination.write(contents)
```

But this throws an error saying: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'value'.

This is what for.fields[wbfile] shows:

```
<django.forms.fields.FileField object at 0x7f91ff1c49d0>
```

Hence the file is definitely bound to the form.

Please help and forgive me if the doubt is too obvious, I am a beginner!

Comment: I didn't get you what you want ?. You have two views one for browse file and another view is access the file. Is it right ?

Comment: I want to pass a file from a template to a view and then to another template and then another view, if that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is everythink you need in the Django documentation.

For FileField : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Try using YourFileField.storage and YourFileField.path to have access to the file.

Then with this doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/

You can use open to open your file in memory. I guess it can give a code like this :

```
storage, path = YourFileField.storage, YourFileField.path
File f = storage.open(path)
```

I don't really understand what you want to do next, but if you want to save the file somewhere else, I guess you can probably use :

```
f.save(path) #or something similar, haven't tested any code like this
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying:

Comment: This is what I'm trying:
I have a browse file option, and a 'Next' button (which is of submit type). On clicking this, 2 options become visible: validate and upload file. 
Browse->Next->Validate->Upload. 
Now when the file is uploaded using the browse option, control shifts to the view and upon rendering, control shifts to a template. Now this happens recursively, I want to preserve the file in each transaction.
(Im using random file names here).
I hope I'm clear!

Comment: Only solution I see would be using a cookie storing the file. I don't understand why you have to move your file from a template to a view (here nothing fancy), then from view to template (why not, for displaying purpose I imagine), but then why again to view?
Also, why aren't you storing your file into a databse?

Comment: I'll look into cookies and the suggested way, clears things up a lot thanks.
The reason why I winded up with this mess was to not clutter the server unnecessarily. I think the design is flawed and will start with a new strategy.